# What does it mean to "pass to the limit" in mathematics?

Tags: probability, limits, finance

I've been reading a finance paper and stumbled upon this phrase. What does **passing to the limit** mean in this context (or overall in mathematics)?

Here is an excerpt from the paper:

> It is straightforward to generalize the example by passing from the
>   time index set {0, 1} to an arbitrary finite discrete time set {0, . .
>   . , T} by considering T independent Bernoulli random variables. This
>   binomial model is called the Cox-Ross-Rubinstein model in finance. It
>   is not difficult — at least with the technology of stochastic calculus
>   that is available today—to pass to the (properly normalized) limit as
>   T tends to infinity, thus ending up with a stochastic process driven
>   by Brownian motion.

Comment: It means "take the limit" or "evaluate the limit" or "compute the limit" ...

Comment: If $f$ is a real-valued function defined on $[0,\infty)$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.